# How to convert Unix Epoch time to PST in Windows C++?

Tags: c++, windows, unix, datetime, epoch

I am trying to convert Unix Epoch time to PST in Windows C++ but my code is failing while converting epoch time of 03/09/2014 10:00. The program first convert epoch time to GMT then Subtract 8 hours from GMT but for 03/09/2014 10:00 time stamp it is giving output 03/09/2014 01:00 instead of 03/09/2014 02:00.? I am using Visual syudi 6.0 version.

May I know where my code is wrong.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<ctime>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct tm * ptm;    
    time_t rawtime = 1394359200;        //  03/09/2014 10:00

    // -- convert UNIX timestamp to GMT time

    ptm = gmtime ( &rawtime );

    printf("\nBEFORE CONVERSION = %04d %02d %02d %02d %02d\n",ptm->tm_year+1900,(ptm-  >tm_mon)+1,ptm->tm_mday,ptm->tm_hour,ptm->tm_min);

    // -- Substract 8 hours from GMT time
    ptm->tm_hour = (ptm->tm_hour) - 8;

    // -- Make time after substaction 
    mktime ( ptm );

    printf("\nAFTER CONVERSION  = %04d %02d %02d %02d %02d\n",ptm->tm_year+1900,(ptm->tm_mon)+1,ptm->tm_mday,ptm->tm_hour,ptm->tm_min);

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0):

You actually should get the timezone of your computer and do the calculations (ie: the `-8`) based on that.

`mktime` sets the `tzname` too, so what does the modified:

```
printf("\n%s\nAFTER CONVERSION  = %04d %02d %02d %02d %02d\n",
       *tzname,ptm->tm_year+1900,(ptm->tm_mon)+1,ptm->tm_mday,
        ptm->tm_hour,ptm->tm_min);
```

print out for you for the time zone name?

For me your app prints (with the modified line) like:

```
BEFORE CONVERSION = 2014 03 09 10 00
CET
AFTER CONVERSION  = 2014 03 09 02 00
```